# Blog url disappears

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, blog

I have a blog with a permalink structure: `domain.com/blog-page/category/postname/`.
 blog-page is a page defined as blogpage via settings.

This works fine so far but the problem is if I am in a category and click on a post the url changes to `domain.com/category/postname`. The blog-page is not displayed anymore.

Yoast is set to keep category, Permalinks is set to `/%category%/%postname%/` and category-base and tag-base are name of blog-page. So why does the blogpage slug disappear when I click on a post.

I don't want to use a plugin. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is how WP is set.

You have set your permalinks structure to `/%category%/%postname%/` so when you click on a post link, you will have that post `/%category%/` and then `/%postname%/`.

I guess you wished to have a structure like `/blog-page/%category%/%postname%/`. well just add this to your permalink settings `/blog-page/%category%/%postname%/`.

Comment: Thank you. Now it shows up but if I click on a post I get a 404 even after saving Permalinks settings again and creating a new post. Is there any other opportunity?

Comment: no that's just it. Do you have any plugin activated or some custom code in your theme files changing the behaviour of your link structure? if so, maybe you should try deactivating your plugins to see witch one is causing the issue.

Comment: Also, assuming you are on an apache server, check your .htaccess file so that it supports mod_rewrite and has the default WP .htaccess rule like here https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Comment: I got it, it works if I remove the slug /blog-page/ from cat and Tag Base. Thank you. But now the question is - how can I get rid of the category and tag Base? I want it to be blog-page as well

Comment: Tag Base is possible but not category. Now it is how I want. Thank you soooooo much

Comment: Hmm now I have the "category" inside the url of the category. How can I remove it?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve now needs deeper customization and you can't have the same "blog-page" base for category, tag and post. you will get the 404 errors you are experiencing.  As for how to remove category and base tag, like I said you need deeper customizations and rewrite the permalink.  You can find plugins like this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/  that will do the job for you